# not running as default in visual studio code

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to run a simple program using inheritance but I keep getting errors like I'm not using python 3 even though I selected it to be the version of python in vs code. This is my code followed by the error.

```
class Student:

    def __init__(self, name, school):

        self.name = name

        self.school = school

        self.marks = []

    def average(self):

        return sum(self.marks) / len(self.marks)


class WorkingStudent(Student):

    def __init__(self, name, school, salary):

        super().__init__(name, school)

        self.salary = salary

    @property
    def weekly_salary(self):

        return self.salary * 40
```

Error:

```
File "/Users/wfeliciano/Documents/VSCode_Workspace_Python/practice.py", line 40, in <module>
    rolf = WorkingStudent('Rolf', 'MIT', 15.50)

File "/Users/wfeliciano/Documents/VSCode_Workspace_Python/practice.py", line 23, in __init__
    super().__init__(name, school)

TypeError: super() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)
```

Comment: Are you sure you are using python 3?

Comment: The error is in your `WorkingStudent` constructor. Change it to `super().__init__(self, name, school)` Let me know if that doesn't fix the problem